# Gradient of fidelity!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

If we have the quantum fidelity function between two states as:

$F(\rho, \sigma)= (Tr \sqrt {\sqrt {\rho } \sigma \sqrt {\rho }})^2$

how we can calculate the gradient/derivative of the function with respect to only one of those two states (e.g. $\sigma$)?

Comment: The same way you compute the gradient with respect to any operator?

Comment: Your question appears to be answered here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800228/derivative-of-mboxtr-left-leftaxa-right-frac12-right-with-respe. However, as discussed in the comments of the answer, I'm not sure what happens if $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt{\rho}$ is non-invertible.